Oil and water configuration in a column
liquids of different densities arrange themselves in layers if they are immiscible: oil and water for a common instance. Let us consider a very long but narrow column filled with water and oil. I want to know whether, after settling, the oil displaces water to the walls(even if marginally) as it sits on top, (what I imagine is: it makes a bowl shape in the water and the water surrounds this bowl shape as it sits against the walls, or is the water oil boundary flat? if the water isn't displaced, is it because they're both fluids (ie. this scenario can’t be treated using the law of flotation as it is used for solids; the water equivalent of the weight of the oil is not displaced); or is it because there is no room in the column for the displacement to occur(ie. the 'moving towards the walls' I imagined isn't an option because the oil also sits on the walls, so it isn't about being solid or fluid)?

Consider the water/air boundary in a glass.  The water cups upward because the water "wets" the glass surface.  Other liquids, e.g. carbon tetrachloride, don't "wet" the glass, and so cup downward.  So, for the oil/water interface, it isn't a weight/displacement question.  This wetting is a function of the liquid's attraction to the glass surface.  So, this question really is which liquid wets the glass better.

Sorry it's taken me a while to reply. Thank you very much for your answer. It's been of great help

If you disregard all forces except gravity, the equilibrium liquid-liquid interface is flat. If the interface were not flat, you could imagine exchanging a small volume of oil at height $h$ with an equal volume of water at height $h + \epsilon$. The volume of water has more mass than the same volume of oil, so by moving it downwards and lifting the oil upwards, energy would be released. Thus the minimum energy configuration must be the one with a flat interface.
It is useful to see why this logic does not work for solids. Consider a block of wood with density 0.75 times that of water. We know that it sits 3/4 submerged. The interface between wood and water isn't flat -- the wood makes a dent in the water. At first glance, you could gain energy by taking a small volume of wood from the bottom of the block and exchanging it with a small volume of water from the surface. But this doesn't actually happen because there is a non-gravitational force present. Wood is solid, and solids are cohesive. The energy you could gain by exchanging the masses is tiny compared to the amount of energy it would take to overcome the cohesive forces and tear the block of wood apart.
Real liquids are cohesive too (though much less so than solids), and there are also adhesion forces with the sides of the container. As such, the surface will not be flat. The shape of the meniscus will be determined by the balance of these forces, which depend on the chemical composition of both of the fluids and the material and shape of the container. For an oil/water interface specifically, the material of the container can induce the water to be either concave (e.g. if the container is glass) or convex (e.g. if the container is teflon).

Sorry I've taken so long to reply. Thank you very much for your answer. What I'm getting is: in the end, it's really a matter of adhesive vs cohesive forces
